# Check if Solr is functioning

Tags: magento-enterprise, solr

I'm wanting to create a test that checks if Solr for Magento Catalog search is functioning on a recurring basis, and then report if it fails. I know there is a connection test button in the admin panel so the functionality already exists.

Questions:

1. Is there already a recurring test checking against Solr? And if so where does it report?
2. If there isn't already a recurring test, what file calls the test?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: If you want to make it yourself - you could always use /ping for your SOLR server - it will respond with a response time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is ready to use method which you can reuse in your custom code eg. in script run by CRON.

I can't provide you code sample as it would break EE license. Just review `Enterprise_Search_Adminhtml_Search_System_Config_TestconnectionController` class and reuse logic.